# Fragments inside ViewPager are not destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my MainActivity in onCreate method I add() MainFragment to FrameLayout main_view_container:

```
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_view_container, new MainFragment(), MainFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

In my MainFragment I have ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter and every page is Fragment itself (PagerFragment).

Then at some point after button click I want to replace whole MainFragment with another Fragment (ReplacementFragment) and add transaction to back stack so I can go back to MainFragment on back button pressed. So I do the following:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_view_container, new ReplacementFragment(), null);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

After I commit transaction MainFragment is stopped and onDestroyView() is called but completely nothing happens with PagerFragments (that are in ViewPager in MainFragment) Not event a single onStop() call. Then when I go back MainFragment's View is recreated in onCreateView() which means new Instance of ViewPager as well, but still nothing with PagerFragments.

How is that possible that in parent Fragment onDestroyView is called but not in children Fragments?

Comment: Did you use getChildFragmentManager() when creating pager adapter inside MainFragment?

Comment: Why don't you open a new activity instead of trying to replace your whole MainFragment with another?

Comment: @cYrixmorten No I didn't, I used Activity's FragmentManager and I guess that's why children fragments were not managed. This solves my case, thank you!

Comment: @Karakuri I could but wanted to know the answer for educational purpose.

Comment: A lucky guess then :-P glad it worked

Comment: @Karakuri if using navigation drawer for instance, then this is the way to go

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must use getChildFragmentManager() when creating pager adapter inside MainFragment.

Comment: Does it really solve? I used getChildFragmentManager() in MainFragment, but the PagerFragments never stop.

Comment: @abdfahim try `mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());`

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you! I feel like I've been trying to fix my fragment manager getting filled up with Pagers for like the last 2 hours and just changing out fragmentManager for childFragmentManager fixed it all.